# Why typescript custom type definitions are included in this project?

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript-typings

I have been studying [this angular 2 project](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and I don't understand, how `src/custom-typings.d.ts` is included? This file contains typescript custom type definitions. There is no `import src/custom-typings.d.ts` in the sources. I can rename this file as anything, I can put this file in any directory and this file will be inlcuded anyway. Even if I change extension to `*.ts` (not `*.d.ts`) it will be included.

I think that because of it my IDE is slow. How to disable auto search of type definitions in all `*.ts` files in the project? I want to include this file manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is loaded by webpack : https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/8e93ae998e76efbd7166e0b0c531396098bd4e34/config/webpack.common.js#L137 which look for all `.*.ts` files excluding `.spec.ts` and `.e2e.ts`

If you don't want it to be loaded by webpack, you could exclude `.d.ts` extension in the loader too and add `/// <reference path="../path_to/custom-typings.d.ts" />` in files where you need these custom typings.

Answer (score 0):

When you write import {} from 'fileName' it automaticlly looks for fileName.d.ts. those files have only the declaration for the function and variable (saying what type they are) not the functions themselves, this is why it still works- the generated js file is still there.

And for the second question- you didn't mention what IDE you have. so I cant answer you.
I didn't understand what you ment in type definitions in all *.ts files... if you don't want to work with type annotations, don't use typescript. and only the type in the function you are working on (and importing) is being looked

Comment: Welcome to SO :) You should comment the question if you need more information to complete your answer rather than commenting into your answer.

Comment: I cannot comment, not enough repo. and I tried to give an answer without all the needed info

Comment: I didn't write 'import {} from custom-typings' but this file is included. If I will rename this file, then this file will be included too. This is why I think that all *.ts files are scanned for type definitions